# NETCF Change font MenuItem

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

What is the font used by a `MenuItem` in a `Windows Mobile` device ? And is there a way to change it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the font name `Nm` in the registry `HKLM\System\GWE\Menu\PopFnt\` seems to do the trick.